# Read Compressed images at runtime + Optimal image compression tool

Tags: java, minecraft

As a challenge and practicality, I have a few images I want to include inside my jar for a mod I'm developing. But as is the compiled jar with the images ends up weighing over 25 MBs, which is not ideal. So my idea is to simply compress them and add that compressed package as a resource. But doing so doesn't appear to shrink the file size that much. So the two questions I want to ask (if that plan makes sense) what's the best way to compress a bunch of images and then being able to utilize them while running the game/program?

Lossy image compression is one way to reduce file size, but when dealing with images that cover the entire screen the drop in quality can easily be noticed, which is not what I want.

Another solution is to simply not have it part of the mod and instead needs to be downloaded individually and read from it. But that's a little cheap and still would have to download the same amount of MBs to get the full experience.

**Note.** I don't need to compress them in my program, just read from them when they are compressed.

Comment: You can put them on an image hosting site or your own server and pull the images at runtime

Comment: jar files are already compressed (they're literally .zip archives).